# Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (217) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, pycharm

I am learning Django and creating a to-do app using the framework. While setting up the Django rest framework API, I got an unusual error. I've been using Django for quite a while, but have never come across this error before. I don't know why this error is getting thrown.

The error occurred the very first time when I executed the command `manage.py runserver` and navigated to `users`.

The error is as below:

```
Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (217) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8001/users/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: Error
Exception Value:    
Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (217) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
Exception Location: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/base64.py, line 87, in b64decode
Python Executable:  /Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/bin/python
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python38.zip',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8',
 '/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
Server time:    Sat, 29 Aug 2020 12:25:01 +0530
```

`views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions
from todo.serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows users to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]


class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint that allows groups to be viewed or edited.
    """
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
```

Below is the stack trace/traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/users/

Django Version: 3.1
Python Version: 3.8.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'todo']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 215, in _get_session
    return self._session_cache

During handling of the above exception ('SessionStore' object has no attribute '_session_cache'), another exception occurred:
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 118, in decode
    return signing.loads(session_data, salt=self.key_salt, serializer=self.serializer)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 135, in loads
    base64d = TimestampSigner(key, salt=salt).unsign(s, max_age=max_age).encode()
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 201, in unsign
    result = super().unsign(value)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 184, in unsign
    raise BadSignature('Signature "%s" does not match' % sig)

During handling of the above exception (Signature "xnqTuv_ylPs2HNImqZUFHZYYDRY5IfETbWXc5_4zbB8" does not match), another exception occurred:
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 114, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 505, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 465, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 476, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 493, in dispatch
    self.initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 410, in initial
    self.perform_authentication(request)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 324, in perform_authentication
    request.user
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 220, in user
    self._authenticate()
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/request.py", line 373, in _authenticate
    user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/authentication.py", line 123, in authenticate
    if not user or not user.is_active:
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 240, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 376, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 23, in <lambda>
    request.user = SimpleLazyObject(lambda: get_user(request))
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/middleware.py", line 11, in get_user
    request._cached_user = auth.get_user(request)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 174, in get_user
    user_id = _get_user_session_key(request)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 58, in _get_user_session_key
    return get_user_model()._meta.pk.to_python(request.session[SESSION_KEY])
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._session[key]
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 220, in _get_session
    self._session_cache = self.load()
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 44, in load
    return self.decode(s.session_data) if s else {}
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 122, in decode
    return self._legacy_decode(session_data)
  File "/Users/yogendrakumar/PycharmProjects/todo_app/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 126, in _legacy_decode
    encoded_data = base64.b64decode(session_data.encode('ascii'))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/base64.py", line 87, in b64decode
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)

Exception Type: Error at /users/
Exception Value: Invalid base64-encoded string: number of data characters (217) cannot be 1 more than a multiple of 4
```

`serializers.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['url', 'username', 'email', 'groups']


class GroupSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['url', 'name']
```

Comment: It seems that the problem is for a field, which contains `base64` string for an image. It is being created from one of the Serializer classes, when this API is being called (`http://127.0.0.1:8001/users/`). Please share code of your both serializer classes (_i.e_ `UserSerializer`, `GroupSerializer` ).

Comment: serializers.py file included

Comment: Since serializer looks good, doesn't have any `base64` string field and has nothing to do with your problem, have you tried clearing your cache and called the API again?

Comment: cleared the cache, but of no use

Comment: Possibly related https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31895, https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/31592

Answer (score 5):

The reason this error crops up because you're on a wrong version of Django. If you haven't changed anything with the version of Django, then the issue most probably is that you've forgotten to activate your correct virtual environment.

Comment: I had the same issue and then I realized that my virtual environment was not active...

Answer (score 4):

Delete all old sessions from the `DJANGO_SESSION` table

Comment: I was working on a fork with new Django version against same database as the earlier - switching back got this error and deleting all sessions cured it. Makes sense - thx

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, but I get the error when my Django version is 3.0.8 and when I upgrade it to 3.1, the problem has been fixed

Answer (score 2):

Clear the browser cache and try again. :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. When writing an answer, you may want to explain why you think your answer is correct, as it may be the case it is not targeting exactly the same problem and the explanation may help to see why

Answer (score 1):

Really dont know why, but clear the cookies from browser fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clear your Browser cache and cookies of all time.

Comment: This was already suggested as a comment and the person said that was no use.

Comment: Opening in a different browser or browser session confirmed that this was a sessions issue for me.

Answer (score -2):

Clear your browsing history: cookies and other side data Then work

Comment: This has already been mentioned in other answers.